# Converting column type to time when over 24 hours

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to change the format of a column from text to time in Power Bi:

[image]

When I change the format to time, anything that is over 24 hours shows as an error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Important thing is - how you wants to show a value greater than 24.

Comment: And please also mention the format in your time column like what 73:30 stands for.

Comment: I would like the value to show as it shows when formatted as text (e.g. if it was 73:30 before then it needs to be 73:30 when re-formatted). 73:30 would be 73 hours and 30 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below **Advanced Editor** code for your purpose.

**Conditions** Values like (73:30) required a delimiter **:** for this code. You can also adjust the code if different delimiter in use.

**Output** will in dd:hh:mm:ss

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjSwMjBQitWJVjKGs8yNrYyBrFgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Time = _t]),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Time", "Time - Copy"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Time - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Time - Copy.1", "Time - Copy.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Time", type text}, {"Time - Copy.1", Int64.Type}, {"Time - Copy.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Time - Copy.1", "hour"}, {"Time - Copy.2", "minutes"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Second", each ([hour]*60*60) + ([minutes]*60)),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each #duration(0,0,0,[Second])),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", type duration}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Input-

[image]

Output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you mkRabbani this is helpful however, I needed to keep it as hours/minutes rather than days/hours/minutes

Comment: Duration/Time data type do not have support for more that 24 in the Hour part. In that case you need to keep the data type of column Text.

Comment: Will that still sum the time correctly though? For example, if 73:30 was added to 00:45 would that then be would that then result in 84:15 or would it result in 73:75?

Comment: Convert that new value as well as the previous column, now you can add (+) both new value.

Comment: Sorry mkRabbani, I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: As we converted the Time text to a duration field, similar way convert the vale you wants to add. then you can simply create another column = duration1+duration2.